# "I think It's totally fine"

Tags: colloquial-language

I just encountered this phrase in [this video](https://youtu.be/5Akk9a_HQRE?t=228):

> 全然いいとおもいます。

As far as I know 全然 is usually used with negatives but can be used in positives, too, in colloquial speech. However, this got me thinking: **what would be a "more grammatically correct way" to say the same**?

"別にいい” also seems colloquial (the man at around 4:20 in the video uses it)

Apart from that, I can think of "結構です”, but it seems to vague; it makes me feel more like I am in a shop or restaurant saying I do not need anything else...

完璧 also seems out of place in this context. It would mean literally "perfect", like attributing a degree to it (good, better, perfect)...

The only other one I found that seems possible to me is 完全に, like "完全にいい", and I found some examples of what seems native speech via Google (「完全にいいぞ. 」「完全にいい1日となりました。」). Seems neutral

However, that's about it. Are there any obvious alternatives that I'm missing?

P.S. What's interesting, the next person used essentially the same construct, "全然いいと思う”, just another level of politeness

Comment: 別にいい is something like "It's okay, I guess". "結構です" is loaded with possible nuance, and can convey irritation, like "I've had enough of this".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a myth that 全然 must be accompanied by a negative word. Quoting from [here](https://news.mynavi.jp/article/20180301-590073/)

- 「一体生徒が全然悪いです」(夏目漱石「坊っちゃん」明治39年)
- 「全然、自分の意志に支配されている」(芥川龍之介「羅生門」大正4年)

These are examples where `全然 + positive` by famous writers.

I think this is gradually 'demystified' over these years and people use `全然 + positive` freely. See e.g. [this](https://style.nikkei.com/article/DGXBZO37057770W1A201C1000000/).

Regarding your question, 全然いいと思います means here *I think there is no problem (if some people are LGBT)*. The point is, it is denying the negativity associated with LGBT by older generation (according to the video). So a natural alternative is 全然問題ないと思います/何の問題もありません.

[Edit] Another possibility is *I don't mind at all*: {全然,まったく} + 気になりません. / 気にしません. /　かまいません.

(I assume it is just like *totally fine* being different from *very good*.  But if both could mean the same, then it should have been *totally ok* perhaps.)

As for others you mention:

- The meaning of 結構です depends on the context, but it is either *No thank you* or *It is very good*. The first does not clearly fit, and neither does the second because it is more for positively valuing the matter under discussion. In the video the speaker is denying the negative value, not positively advocating LGBT.
- 完全にいい will be understood, but it is not acceptable (not something a native speaker would say). And again, this sounds more for positively valuing the thing - so does not fit for the context of the video either.

Comment: Thank you. The only thing left unclear for me is the 'naturalness' of 完全にいい。I understand that simply googling is not proof, but there seem to be quite a few hits for 完全にいい and its variations (like [this one](https://twitter.com/kiha183_rainbow/status/1352834708296540160) I chose at random) which seem to be written by natives. Possibly, these are conscious choices to write something unusual, like "that totes fine"? Or maybe just a common mistake?

Comment: I googled as well. At least I don't see 完全にいい used by itself.  Either it modifies something or 完全に is not modifying いい.  An example of the former: 完全にいい状態で, of the latter 完全にいいところ持っていかれた (完全に mods 持っていかれた). The linked tweet is something of mix - 完全に modifies the whole bracketed phrase, and not really an example of 完全にいい.  I can confirm 完全にいい cannot be used as an independent sentence to mean _It is perfectly good_ (at least very unlikely to be uttered by a native speaker as a standalone sentence).

Comment: @sundowner とってもいい would be used. 絶対いい is possible.

Comment: ＠Kaz 絶対にいい is unlikely to be used by itself. とてもいい is of course fine. 363/26/3 examples returned for とてもいい/絶対いい/完全にいい in [BCCWJ](https://bonten.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/string_search)

Comment: @sundowner First time I see that resource, will make sure to use it from now. Thank you again